# how to create different webforms for different types of users in a Asp.net website given their logins

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, asp.net, vs-web-site-project

I am currently working on the website of a hospital management system. I do know how to create a login form and how to code it. The problem is that I have multiple types of users:

- doctors: will view information about their patients and the coming appointments
- Nurse: Will see what room is she assigned to in a specific time and what client she's attending
- Receptionist: will have access to information about the client and add/delete/modify an appointment

How can I sort of enable some web forms to doctors only, or nurses only, or receptionists only based on their username/password ?

Comment: What's your Visual Studio Version ?

Comment: Visual Studio Entreprise 2015

Answer (score 0):

You can Manage it using Membership built in feature in Visual Studio, where you can manage roles for different types of Users !!!

For more details..refer the following link...
https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/t32yf0a9(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you able to do that, do everything yourself over database. You have some table *Users*, which contains logins and passwords. Add also field *Role* or create one more table *Roles* and in table *Users* create foreign key for table *roles*.
Then you might create few masterpages, one for each role, where you can design one masterpage fully for one role, another masterpage for another role, so on. And you should check on load for the role.

Another way is making everything dynamically. For example, in database you will create some table *menus*, where for every role you will create specific menu, and then call this menu on load for some specific role.